# Turning off power to usb port. Or turn off power to entire usb subsystem

Tags: kernel, usb, power-management

I have a usb lamp which I specifically bought in order to turn it off programmatically at a certain time, thus I need to remove the power to its usb port.

I believe I have a usb-hub at usb6. The lamp is connected to one of the ports in this hub:

```
#myhost$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
...
...
Bus 008 Device 006: ID 050d:0234 Belkin Components F5U234 USB 2.0 4-Port Hub
```

Here's what I've tried:

Two solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux), the first suggests:

```
echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup 
echo suspend > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level  # turn off
```

but I get `write error: Invalid argument` when trying to write to `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/level`:

```
$sudo bash -c 'echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/wakeup'
$echo suspend|sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/level suspend
tee: /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/level: Invalid argument
$sudo bash -c 'echo suspend> /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/level'bash: line 0: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

The second solution:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/autosuspend_delay_ms; echo auto > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/control'
```

which does turn off power to the usb-hub device.

I was also trying to follow [this](https://loginroot.com/power-off-and-on-usb-device-in-linux-ubuntu/):

But the output of `lsusb -t` just hangs:

```
$lsusb -t
4-1:0.0: No such file or directory
4-1:0.1: No such file or directory
^C
```

Which prevents me from using this method to get the '2-1.1' part to this:

```
echo '2-1.1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

Is there an alternative way of getting this information?

Alternatively, is there a way to shut off power to the entire usb subsystem? Something like `modprobe -r usb_etc`?

My kernel is:

```
$uname -r
3.2.0-4-amd64
```

Comment: what syntax errors? in this case, there's no need to quote the simple strings 'suspend', 'disabled'. if you're into a habit of quoting, great for you, but in this case it's not needed.

Comment: I tried stracing the `lsusb -t` call and I didn't find anything useful within the time I had to debug it. I honestly don't have time right now to find bugs in lsub, and I can't even reproduce it right now, so it probably depends on the devices that are plugged in. I'll have to wait to get home to try to reproduce it.

Comment: _...file named "level"; this
file was deprecated as of the 2.6.35 kernel and replaced by the
"control" file._ https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt

Answer (score 39):

You could use my tool [**uhubctl**](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) - command line utility to control USB power per port for compatible USB hubs.

It works only on hubs that support per-port power switching, but note that many modern motherboards have USB hubs that support this feature.

First off, your OS may already have uhubctl present in package repositories, refer to [README](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl) for how to install it, but make sure you use most recent version (2.4.0 as of this writing).

If your OS does not have recent version of this package, you can install it from source as follows:

To compile:

```
git clone https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl
cd uhubctl
make
```

To install system-wide as `/usr/sbin/uhubctl`:

```
sudo make install
```

To list status of all hubs, their locations and ports that can be controlled by uhubctl:

```
sudo uhubctl
```

(you can avoid using `sudo` if you configure udev USB permissions).

To turn off power on port 5 of single compatible hub:

```
sudo uhubctl -a 0 -p 5
```

If you have more than one compatible hub connected, use `-l` to specify hub location to control it:

```
sudo uhubctl -a 0 -p 5 -l 3-1.2
```

To toggle power off then on:

```
sudo uhubctl -a 2 -p 5
```

Note that USB 3.0 hubs are also supported, and quite a few new USB 3.0 hubs actually work well.

Read [more here](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl).

Comment: A little more information would be nice. Especially because you're the author and it's not a standard package examples of how to use it, what if any capabilities/limitations it has, risks if any,  Link only answers are not preferred.

Comment: Well, copy/pasting whole [README](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/blob/master/README.md) file doesn't seem like bright idea to me. It has all caveats explained.

Comment: No, the whole readme would be excessive. Just how you can use the program to solve the problem posed in the question. And if there are any caveats to that particular use case, not the whole application. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my first comment.

Comment: FYI: This method does work for the Renesas UPD720202 family of PCIe-USB host controllers. :)  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Wossname. Do you mind adding it as new issue at https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/issues ? I will update supported devices list.

Comment: How do you turn it on/off using device and product id? For example `sudo uhubctl -a 1 0bda:a811`?

Comment: `uhubctl -n 0bda:a811 -a 1`

Comment: @mvp I think one thing that would improve this answer is to briefly explain the underlying API or mechanism that this program is using to switch ports on/off. I also couldn't clearly see this information in the README on Github.

Comment: How does the `3-1.2` notation translate into the bus/port notation used in the output of `lsusb -t`?

Comment: It does not directly. Hub locations look like b-x.y.z, where b is USB bus number, and x, y, z... are port numbers for all hubs in chain, starting from root hub for a given USB bus. This address is semi-stable - it will not change if you unplug/replug (or turn off/on) USB device into the same physical USB port

Answer (score 28):

See [Controlling a USB power supply (on/off) with linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702216/controlling-a-usb-power-supply-on-off-with-linux), short version, for newer kernels "suspend" does not work anymore:

```
echo "0" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/autosuspend_delay_ms"
echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/control"
```

But it doesn't literally cut the power: it signals the device to poweroff, and it's up to the device to implement power management and do the right thing.

You have a lot of details in the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt) in the kernel, there it explains the various files in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/.../power/` and how to manage the devices and ports.

For things that are not real USB devices (does your USB lamp show up in lsusb?) you might be out of luck, I have tried myself with an usb lamp and with a GPS logger that charges its battery and transfers data through USB that shows up as a cp210x USB-to-serial, and neither does poweroff. I can "disconnect" the GPS with `echo '5-4.6' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` and reconnect it with `echo '5-4.6' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` but the battery charging light is always on.

But it seems that [some hubs do it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3246415/869019).

Comment: Thank you for that clear followup