# How to switch 5v USB on/off?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, c

I purchased a HMI(Human-Machine Interface -Exor Esmart04) running on Linux with kernel version 3.10.12. On this HMI there is a USB port which outputs 5V, this 5V I'm trying to switch on/off using a C script. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look new post, updated it a bit.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165447/85039 In particular , https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/321945/85039 links to github of a C utility, so you could read their source code