# How to disable USB power in standby/suspend

Tags: ubuntu, usb, power-management

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on a MSI X570-A PRO mainboard. Kernel is 5.11.0-37-lowlatency.
I've connected an USB soundcard, an Elgato Stream Deck and a Novation Launchpad X to it.
I usually don't shutdown my computer completely but just go into standby/suspend, so I can resume my work easily on the next day without starting every previously running program again.

My issue is that all these USB devices are still powered during standby. Now I am searching for an option to turn of the power of the USB ports during standby so I don't have to disconnect my devices manually. Up to now I didn't find such an option and similar questions on stackexchange are 10 years old or older and are talking about kernel versions around version 2.6.x. I also poked around in the BIOS but wasn't able to find an option for that.

I hope you can help me with that so my devices won't light up half of the room unnecessarily.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning off power to usb port. Or turn off power to entire usb subsystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165447/turning-off-power-to-usb-port-or-turn-off-power-to-entire-usb-subsystem) https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/run-scripts-and-commands-on-suspend-and-resume-on-linux/ https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/

Comment: BTW, on my very modern motherboard based on the AMD X570 chipset I cannot disable or power off any of devices or ports. So much for USB3 power features.